# Segmentation fault when trying to compare calling object with another object

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have following code wherein I am trying to compare this object with another object. But when I try to run It gives segmentation fault.  While telling me what changes to be made also tell me why this throws segmentation fault

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class opo
{
    public:
    bool operator==(opo temp);
};
bool opo::operator==(opo temp)
{
    if(*this == temp)
    {
        cout<<"same\n";
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"diff\n";
        return false;
    }
}

int main()
{
    opo a1,a2;
    a1==a2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Funny.  *How do you know if two objects are equal?* -- Answer -- *They're equal because they're equal*.  That's what your code is saying.

Comment: Oh thanks for that comment. really helped me understand the problem & solve it

Answer (score 3):

You have a infinite recursive loop.

```
if(*this == temp)
```

calls `bool operator==(opo temp)` which contains the if statement which in turn call the function again and so on.  This will cause the program to run out of resources eventually cause a stack overflow or segfault.

When you ceck for equality you need to check the members.  Since you class is stateless(no members) any two objects should be equal.

If you had class members like

```
class Foo
{
public:
    int a, b;
};
```

Then we would have a comparison object like

```
bool Foo::operator ==(const Foo & rhs)
{
    return a == rhs.a && b == rhs.b;
    // or with std::tie
    return std::tie(a, b) == std::tie(rhs.a, rhs.b);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
bool opo::operator==(opo temp)
{
    if(*this == temp) // calls this->operator==(temp)
```

This just calls the *same* function again, leading to an infinite recursion and, eventually, stack overflow.

You need to come up with some actual way to tell if two objects are identical, and then do that.

As an aside, your operator's signature is *weird*. You're forcing a temporary copy of the right-hand-side argument (`a2` in your original code). A more normal implementation might look like

```
struct opo {
    int m_value = 0;
    bool operator== (opo const &) const;
};

bool opo::operator==(opo const &other) const {
    // actually compare something
    return m_value == other.m_value;
}
```

Notes:

1. we take the right-hand-side argument by reference, meaning we don't create a temporary copy
2. we take it by *const* reference, meaning we promise not to change it (why would you change something while comparing it?)
3. our operator is also marked `const`, so we'er promising not to change the left-hand-side either
4. I added a member so I have something to compare